# Laravel throws errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" despite the correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I am trying to add a table containing two foreign keys, see below:

```
Schema::create('semester_cohorts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('semester_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cohort_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('semester_id')
            ->references('semesters')
            ->on('id')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('cohort_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('cohorts')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I get the following message: `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table [table name](errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")`, even though the respective referenced tables exist in the database, there are no typos in names and the types of primary/foreign keys match. What could cause this problem?
`

Answer (score 4):

You got `references` and `on` mixed up in your first foreign key:

```
$table->foreign('semester_id')
            ->references('semesters')
            ->on('id')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

should be

```
$table->foreign('semester_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('semesters')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems possible here:

- Check column types for both tables, types should be the same
- Try to split migrations. Firstly create table **semester_cohorts** then below use

  ```
  Schema::table('semester_cohorts', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreign('semester_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('semesters')
          ->onDelete('cascade');

      $table->foreign('cohort_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('cohorts')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this issue and its because of the type `unsignedBigInteger`.

Foreign key column must be the same data type as the primary key it references.

So if your *primary key* in `semesters` & `cohorts` table is of type `bigIncrements`

you should define the Foreign key type as `BigInteger` then follow it with an `unsigned()`:

```
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('semester_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('cohort_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
```

**Edit:**

Like kerbholz said you have an error in defining the foreign keys

Comment: Primary key in both of these tables is unsignedBigInteger (or, to be exact bigIncrements which return unsignedBigInteger)